# boto3 aws remove all inbound security group rules

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I need to remove all security group rules from a security group.
I' getting the rules by using:

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
sg = ec2.SecurityGroup('sg-someID')

sg.ip_permissions
```

but I'm not sure how to loop through it using the revoke_ingress command

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just call `revoke_ingress()` and pass the rules you want to delete. Since you want to delete all rules, pass the entire rules array.

```
sg.revoke_ingress(IpPermissions=sg.ip_permissions)
```

From: [revoke_ingress](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.SecurityGroup.revoke_ingress)

Comment: `revoke_ingress()` and `revoke_egress()` throw on an empty list so this needs `if sg.ip_permissions:` to be fully reliable.